# Convert a <language> project/module into a <other language> project/module

Tags: intellij-idea

For a project created by Intellij IDEA, how to convert a type of project/module to another type ?

for example :

java to maven 
java to groovy
maven to java
......

tank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way to convert Java to Groovy and IntelliJ IDEA native project to Maven or Gradle build system project.

Related requests:

- [IDEABKL-6990](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6990) Export IDEA project configuration to external build system (Maven, Gradle)
- [IDEA-50321](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-50321) Convert Java to Groovy code